Rails module constant did not work with Zeitwerk
I have this code in /lib/my_app/version.rb
module MyApp
  VERSION = '3.0.7'
end

When I tried this MyApp::VERSION, I saw this error: uninitialized constant MyApp::VERSION.
Then I tried to add config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("lib"), and a new error happened: expected file /Users/Documents/big_app/lib/my_app/version.rb to define constant MyApp::Version, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)
The only solution that worked for me was to add require_relative '../lib/my_app/version' to application.rb config file. But I think it's not the right solution.
Any idea about this issue?

If what you're looking to do is just version your Rails application you can just keep it simple and place the constant in config/application.rb which is required in the boot process anyways and includes a module encapsulating your application.
# ...
module MyApp
  VERSION = '3.0.7'
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 7.0
  end
end


The only solution that worked for me was to add require_relative '../lib/my_app/version' to application.rb config file. But I think it's not the right solution.

It's less wrong than your other attempt.
Zeitwerk is really for loading the classes and modules in your application. Constants that are simple scalar values do not need a separate file and autoloaded constants are not available at boot time.
In gems you typically include the version in the lib/my_gem.rb file which is largely boilerplate anyways. This doesn't make much sense to emulate in a Rails app though.
If you really want a separate file which is done in some gems simply to reduce the amount of churn in the version history of the gemspec file then you just require it manually.
require Rails.root.join('lib/my_app/version')

However again, does this actually make any sense in the context of a Rails app?
lib in Rails is commonly used for code that doesn't quite fit into /app and should not be autoloaded. It's the purgatory that code lives in until it's extracted into a separate gem. It's not a very obvious place to place something that's just config.

"Zeitwerk is really for loading the classes and modules in your application." this is not the case, actually. Zeitwerk is about autoloading constants, their values do not matter. Your recommendation of just throwing that in config/application.rb is a good one and I second it, but having a version.rb file is also legit and very idiomatic in gems. Zeitwerk autoloads the version.rb file in gems routinely (and for_gem sets a gem inflector that special-cases the version file for you automatically).

@XavierNoria kind of. Normal constants will break the inflection scheme since they by convention are all-caps and it's pretty rare that you have a constant that actually warants being in its own file thats not a module or constant. The gem version is kin  of the exception that proves the rule as that's treated as a special case in the gem loader setup.

No, no, I disagree. Users can put the constants wherever they want as long as they follow the conventions. That is supported and it is an accepted practice, up to the user. Zeitwerk provides arbitrary constant autoloading, not class/module autoloading. If you want to put an integer in one file, you can do that, it is supported, and the design of the inflectors is so that you can inflect by individual file if you want. (Disclaimer: I am the author of Zeitwerk.)

Yes, but does it actually do anything positive for the code quality? That's kind of my point.

Having a version file with a constant that stores a string not only is super common in Ruby, it certainly does not conflict with my notion of code quality. I get your point though, it does for you.

There may be several things going on here.
First, if lib is not in the autoload paths, Zeitwerk is not managing the file. You've go to manually load it, and this is totally fine.
Then, if lib is in the autoload paths, you need to tell the autoloader inflector that my_app/version.rb should be camelized as VERSION, not Version. Please check the autoloading guide about that.
Finally, in that case, you cannot refer to the constant while the application boots, because while booting reloadable constants are not available. Please let me know if you need that and I'll followup.

I really don't think you should set up an inflection as this constant should not be autoloaded in the first place. There is no good reason to potentially break if your app ever wants to use Version as model name in the future.

As I said, the inflection is needed ASSUMING you want the file to be autoloaded. Otherwise, the second paragraph of the reply applies. Secondly, with Zeitwerk you are able to configure inflections down to the individual file, they do not have to be global.

Yes, You are right but instead of using relative path, use your code as it was before with specified file if it's only one file you want to load.
In your version.rb use below code.
lib/my_app/version.rb
module MyApp
  VERSION = '3.0.7'.freeze
end

Here .freeze is define constant in your file and it'll load by Zeitwerk(Autoloader of your app).
This will resolve your issue.

Thanks, but I have tried your solution, and the result is still the same.

can you just share more details of you error? @Kyle

It's still the same, uninitialized constant MyApp::VERSION (NameError)
And if I add config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("lib"), it can not start and raise an error as I explained in the question.

@Kyle after adding config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("lib") to your application.rb you are restarting  your application. Right?

Yes, for sure @Akshay

Did you have changed your Zeitwork configuration? @Kyle. otherwise it should work properly with you path of lib folder

@Kyle use this in your application config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', '**/')].

This is just a bad answer. You do not need or want a separate file for simple constants. Its not a class or module.
